# How to update time value for a unique constraint in TimescaleDB without making duplicate rows?

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb

I want to have rows in my table with unique domains (ex: google.com) with a time associated with each domain.

The domains should be unique, and I want to update the time value when I start processing a domain. I can't figure out how to Upsert/(insert/update) a time value for a unique domain however using TimescaleDB.

EX: I don’t want duplicate rows for ‘google.com’ in my table, which seems impossible since time is also a unique constraint.
Is there a way to get around this?

Ideally I want my rows to look like:

```
google.com - <time>
cnn.com - <time>
and NOT
google.com - <time 1>
google.com - <time 2>
cnn.com - <time 1>
```

```
Here’s my schema:
CREATE TABLE
  domain_rechecks (
    domain VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    requeue_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    requeued_at TIMESTAMP,
    UNIQUE(domain, requeue_at)
  );
SELECT
  create_hypertable (‘domain__rechecks’, ‘requeue_at’);
```

Is there any way to do this using timescaledb? Or do I need to look for a different solution? Thanks!

Comment: *"I want to update the time value"*: so you want to update `requeue_at`, right? Why do you think this is impossible - what did you try and what error did you get? And why do you need **upsert** instead of a simple **update**?

Comment: *"I don’t want duplicate rows for ‘google.com’ in my table"*: Then you should make `domain` a (unique) primary key, right? And why would you create a hypertable, when you only ever have 1 timestamp per domain?

Comment: @TmTron you can't update requeue_at because it is a constraint of timescaledb hypertables. It requires the time key to be an index, but I also want the domain to be an index. I thought I would need a hypertable for 1 time per domain because I still want to do time chunking, like get all domains I haven't processed for the past 7 days or so.

Comment: Try to create a secondary table with single results of the duplicates and delete all of the duplicates and then restore only the non duplicated lines.

Comment: This isn't a great usecase for a hypertable at all, this should just be a normal table